# Unnexpected error while pivoting table in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, syntax-error

I currently have a table with the following info:

| month | age_of_opps | number_of_opps |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 0 - 10 | 10 |
| 2021-01-01 | 11 - 20 | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 | 21 - 30 | 7 |
| 2021-02-01 | 0 - 10 | 2 |
| 2021-02-01 | 11 - 20 | 20 |
| 2021-02-01 | 21 - 30 | 12 |

(And so on)

I need to pivot the column "age_of_opps", and keep just one line for each month, summing up the number of opps in each cell, like this:

| month | 0 - 10 | 11 - 20 | 21 - 30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 10 | 1 | 7 |
| 2021-02-01 | 2 | 20 | 12 |

I tried the following query, but I keep on getting a "syntax error: unexpected string literal '0-10'" on the first CASE WHEN statement line of base_two:

```
WITH base_one AS(
SELECT 
   month,
   CASE 
        WHEN ROUND(AVG(DATE_DIFF(CAST(current_date AS DATE), CAST(creation_date AS DATE), DAY))) BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN '0-10'
        WHEN ROUND(AVG(DATE_DIFF(CAST(current_date AS DATE), CAST(creation_date AS DATE), DAY))) BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN '11-20'
        WHEN ROUND(AVG(DATE_DIFF(CAST(current_date AS DATE), CAST(creation_date AS DATE), DAY))) BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN '21-30'
        WHEN ROUND(AVG(DATE_DIFF(CAST(current_date AS DATE), CAST(creation_date AS DATE), DAY))) BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40'
        WHEN ROUND(AVG(DATE_DIFF(CAST(current_date AS DATE), CAST(creation_date AS DATE), DAY))) BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '41-50'
        WHEN ROUND(AVG(DATE_DIFF(CAST(current_date AS DATE), CAST(creation_date AS DATE), DAY))) BETWEEN 51 AND 60 THEN '51-60'
        END AS age_of_opps,
    COUNT(*) AS opps_per_age

FROM `fictional_db_1` 

GROUP BY 1
),

base_two AS(
SELECT  
     month,
     CASE WHEN age_of_opps = '0-10' THEN SUM(opps_per_age) END AS '0-10',
     CASE WHEN age_of_opps = '11-20' THEN SUM(opps_per_age) END AS '11-20',
     CASE WHEN age_of_opps = '21-30' THEN SUM(opps_per_age) END AS '21-30',
     CASE WHEN age_of_opps = '31-40' THEN SUM(opps_per_age) END AS '31-40',
     CASE WHEN age_of_opps = '41-50' THEN SUM(opps_per_age) END AS '41-50',
     CASE WHEN age_of_opps = '51-60' THEN SUM(opps_per_age) END AS '51-60'

FROM base_one

GROUP BY 1
```

I am not sure to proceed, since I need to write the name of the column in between single quotes... please help!

Comment: String literals cannot be column names. Rename your columns and let the presentation app do beautiful names. Or use [backtick](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#identifiers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation::

```
select month,
       sum(case when age_of_opps = '0 - 10' then number_of_opps end) as num_0_10,
       sum(case when age_of_opps = '11 - 20' then number_of_opps end) as num_11_20,
       sum(case when age_of_opps = '21 - 30' then number_of_opps end) as num_21-30
from t
group by month
```

Answer (score 0):

[IF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#if) is BigQuery-specific, but a bit shorter:

```
select month,
       sum(if(age_of_ops = '0 - 10', opps_per_age, 0)) as age_0_10,
       sum(if(age_of_ops = '11 - 20', opps_per_age, 0)) as age_11_20,
       sum(if(age_of_ops = '21 - 30', opps_per_age, 0)) as age_21_30,
from base_one
group by month
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below solution

```
select * from
  (select * from `project.dataset.your_table`)
  pivot(sum(number_of_opps) for age_of_opps in ('0 - 10' _0_10, '11 - 20' _11_20, '21 - 30' _21_30))
```

if to apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]